# randomly picking skspritenode node to spawn out of 5 sprites

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, arc4random

i have 5 skspritesnodes, i want to spawn 1 random node at a time, i know i have to use arc4random but the examples ive tried dont seem to work.  Id like a variable i can then input where ever i need start spawning random looking "enemys"

```
var bird0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "back_bird")
var bird1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blue_bird")
var bird2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green_bird")
var bird3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "purple_bird")
var bird4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "orange_bird")
```

i have the physicsbody set for each, size, ect.  everything is all set minus the ability to randomly pick one to come out

Comment: General note: if your variable names contain incrementing numbers you are almost always better off using an array. That simplifies the entire "pick a random one" as well.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Sweeper's answer, you can make an extension:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

extension Array {
    var randomElement: Element {
        return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))]
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let sprites = [
        SKSpriteNode(color: .brown, size: CGSize(width:100,height:100)),
        SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width:100,height:100)),
        SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width:100,height:100)),
        SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width:100,height:100)),
        ]

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        if let randomBird = sprites.randomElement.copy() as? SKSpriteNode{

            if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self){
                randomBird.position = location
                addChild(randomBird)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why store the nodes in an array when all you're doing is copying them? You'll end up with _n_ nodes that are never used.

Comment: @Epsilon That (copying) was my way to let the OP spawn nodes multiple times instead of to add them just once (because node can have only one parent). The point was actually an extension which allows a bit convenient way to get a random element. Make sense?

Comment: I understand why you copied the nodes. My issue is with the array itself. I think a function with a switch statement makes more sense.

Comment: @Epsilon Could work ( eg. randomizing index and returning a sprite in a switch). But I can find a problem with that too :p Have you heard about pooling ? Say that you spawn sprites fast...It is always a way more performant to have them pre-allocated in an array, rather than spawning them in a switch when needed. And that is what your method would do.

Comment: Also when I said, randomizing an index, I meant randomizing a value between say 0 and 1 and based on that, return a sprite. So no array. But I  would stick to an array and pre-allocated nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure this method is considered pooling (pre-allocating) or if copying a node is faster than allocating a new one.

Comment: @Epsilon Pre-allocating nodes and storing them into an array is considered as part of pooling. Later on you are re-using them or creating a new ones if needed. What do you consider as pooling? By the way where did I mention that copying is faster than allocating ? Copying has nothing with pooling stuff I mentioned.

Comment: I assumed you meant your answer is pooling. You can easily pool with a function/switch statement as well.

Comment: @Epsilon Nope, I just commented your solution without an array. Pool from where?

Comment: You can pre-allocated all the nodes you're need and select them randomly with a switch

Comment: @Epsilon Okay, but where do you store your nodes  after allocating them?

Comment: @Epsilon Not in an array, right? :) You probably had in mind something more appropriate ...

Comment: I'm not trying to be critical of your approach. I was curious why you (and the other answerer) chose to use an array to select a random sprite when you would need to copy or create a new sprite prior to adding it to the scene.

Comment: @Epsilon Because I started with idea that sprites will be pre-created, and stored in array and reused rather than created at spawn time because based on how often they spawn, and what texture they load or how many children they have, a lag can happen. Also, IMO but that's just me, I think your switch statement might look nasty if you have must to have many cases.

Comment: Also you don't  have to copy those sprites nor to create new ones in order to add them to the scene. You just use them, and before adding them to the scene, you check if they are available to be added, eg. check if they have a parent.

Comment: @Epsilon If you're game is going to have n sprites only, then pre-allocating them in an array makes sense as it's easy to iterate over them and/or choose one at random to put int he scene. If you're going to have lots of sprites of n different types, it still makes sense to put them in an array as the array can be the 'factory' that spawns new sprites easily. Yes, you'll have n unused SKSpriteNodes, but I suspect the overhead is very small. No matter what you do, you have to create or copy a sprite before adding it to the scene, unless you pre-allocate every single sprite possible.

Comment: @SteveIves I have no problem with using arrays. Look at this answer, as implemented, and tell me if this is how you'd solve this problem.

Comment: @EpsilonvIt looks pretty good - Whirlwind's answers are trustworthy.  But I think thus is a situation where there are lots of 'right' answers. For example, this could be implemented by iterating over an array of colours to create an array of sprites. Not saying that would be a better way, just an alternative if the sprites are all the same except for one attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the sprites in an array. Then, you can access a random element in that array.

Here's a function that returns a random bird.

```
func randomBird() -> SKSpriteNode {
    let array = [bird0, bird1, bird2, bird3, bird4]
    return array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]
}
```

You can also, put all the birds in an array and remove the variables `bird0`, `bird1`, `bird2` and so on:

```
let birds = [
    SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "back_bird"),
    SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blue_bird"),
    SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green_bird"),
    SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "purple_bird"),
    SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "orange_bird")
]
```

Then `birds[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]` will get you a random bird.

Comment: it wasnt to fix it "UInt32(birds.count).  then if i "fix" it, it says it "cannon subscript value of type SKspritenode with an index type of UInt32"

Comment: @TroyDeJ I've edited my answer. See if it works. If it does, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark! Also, I recommend you to install the SwiftRandom pod: https://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandomhttps://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandom

Comment: sorry for being a total beginner but how do you integrate that? since `birds[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]` isnt a node but an int

Comment: @TroyDeJ Trust me, it is a node. Let me explain. `UInt32(array.count)` turns `array.count` into a uint32 so that it can be used to call `arc4random_uniform`. But `arc4random_uniform` returns a uint32. So I need to convert the return value back to an `Int` so that it can be used to access the array using the subscript syntax. Since `birds` is of type `[SKSpriteNode]`, accessing it using `[]` returns a `SKSpriteNode`. Try it!

Comment: got it to work between both of your answers, much appreciated.  How can i add physicsbodies to those sprites now?  since they are in that array i dont want to ruin it

Comment: @TroyDeJ Just loop through the array using a loop like `for bird in birds { }` and add physics bodies to each bird.

Comment: while i have your ear, any reason i cant change sprite size in the "for in"? i can add physcis, but when i use CGsize, it applies 1 size to all, even tho then need to be different sizes. pretty odd.

Comment: @TroyDeJ that's expected behaviour of `for in` loops. You use it to do the _same_ thing to all the items in a sequence. So if you want to set different sizes to each sprite, use subscript to access tge individual sprites instead: `birds[0]`, `birds[1]` etc.